# web3.personal.ecRecover doesn't return the right public address

Tags: javascript, ethereum, web3js

I'm trying to get web3.personal.ecRecover to work.
This is my setup:

- Chrome using Remix IDE
- MetaMask to inject web3.js

Now I'm trying the following commands in the Chrome Dev Console:

```
msg = web3.sha3('Schoolbus')

web3.eth.sign(web3.eth.accounts[0], msg , function(error, result){
     if(!error)
         console.log(result)
    else
        console.error(error);
})
```

this returns:

```
0xd030d9a04df643f62a1502b017f51c41a659268091abbd20e2de97b935724d7c
```

Now I set:

```
 signature = "0x36f32cbd6133ce6be7efa4cb73ff3f9ddf9b7db3ba15fa543ab0a93d04a96c102693739f946f2d89eca9030b4c8e01bb6fada1c23f05b6a4956dd63deaf187501b"
```

and try:

```
web3.personal.ecRecover(msg,signature, function(error, result){
    if(!error)
        console.log(result)
    else
        console.error(error);
})
```

and get:

```
0xcc3f70c6caa9fee58bab68f292bdf3132c3c9ae2
```

Obviously this is not the public address I used in (i.e web3.eth.accounts[0])

Any suggestions to fix this issue?

Answer (score 7):

After messing around with this for a few hours I finally found a working solution.

Instead of using web3.eth.personal.ecRecover use web3.eth.accounts.recover

```
const Web3 = require('web3');
const web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider('http://node.expanse.tech'));

let test = {
      address: web3.eth.accounts[0],
      msg: "this is a test",
      sig: "0x689f9d5718e3a4ecb643d27742c60bde7bee66a596a4593ae00ca853b8c6ea5d1ffb5b72112b053ccdcb31c4640f90bfb47b543e644437c6b23cd5f24f4e83b41b",
      version: "2"
    }

  let key = web3.eth.accounts.recover(test.msg, test.sig);

console.log(key)
```

Answer (score 2):

You should use `web3.personal.sign` instead of `web3.eth.sign` 
https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/web3-eth-personal.html#sign

Comment: it's supported. https://medium.com/metamask/the-new-secure-way-to-sign-data-in-your-browser-6af9dd2a1527